# Trailing slash triggers 404 in Flask path rule

Tags: python, flask

I want to redirect any path under `/users` to a static app.  The following view should capture these paths and serve the appropriate file (it just prints the path for this example).  This works for `/users`, `/users/604511`, and `/users/604511/action`.  Why does the path `/users/` cause a 404 error?

```
@bp.route('/users')
@bp.route('/users/<path:path>')
def serve_client_app(path=None):
    return path
```

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Your `/users` route is missing a trailing slash, which Werkzeug interprets as an explicit rule to not match a trailing slash.  Either add the trailing slash, and Werkzeug will redirect if the url doesn't have it, or set [`strict_slashes=False`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/routing/#rule-format) on the route and Werkzeug will match the rule with or without the slash.

```
@app.route('/users/')
@app.route('/users/<path:path>')
def users(path=None):
    return str(path)

c = app.test_client()
print(c.get('/users'))  # 302 MOVED PERMANENTLY (to /users/)
print(c.get('/users/'))  # 200 OK
print(c.get('/users/test'))  # 200 OK
```

```
@app.route('/users', strict_slashes=False)
@app.route('/users/<path:path>')
def users(path=None):
    return str(path)

c = app.test_client()
print(c.get('/users'))  # 200 OK
print(c.get('/users/'))  # 200 OK
print(c.get('/users/test'))  # 200 OK
```

---

You can also set `strict_slashes` for all URLs.

```
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

However, you should avoid disabling strict slashes in most cases. The docs explain why:

> This behavior allows relative URLs to continue working even if the trailing slash is omitted, consistent with how Apache and other servers work. Also, the URLs will stay unique, which helps search engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

Answer (score 66):

To disable strict slashes GLOBALLY; set `url_map.strict_slashes = False` like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

This way you do not have to use `strict_slashes=False` for each view.

Then you just define the route without a trailing slash like so:

```
bp = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
@bp.route('/my-route', methods=['POST'])
```

Then `/my-route` and `/my-route/` both work identically.

Comment: How would we do strict slashes for Blueprints without defining it for each view?

Comment: @jchi2241 Missed your comment for a year-- sorry. The example is using blueprints, you configure on the app level.

Answer (score 20):

It's because of Werkzeug’s consistency with other HTTP servers. Have a look at Flask's [Quickstart documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior). The relevant paragraph:

> ### Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior
>
> Flask’s URL rules are based on Werkzeug’s routing module. The idea
> behind that module is to ensure beautiful and unique URLs based on
> precedents laid down by Apache and earlier HTTP servers.
>
> Take these two rules:
>
> ```
> @app.route('/projects/') 
> def projects():
>     return 'The project page'
>
> @app.route('/about') 
> def about():
>     return 'The about page'
> ```
>
> Though they look rather similar, they differ in their use of the
> trailing slash in the URL definition. In the first case, the canonical
> URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. In that sense, it
> is similar to a folder on a file system. Accessing it without a
> trailing slash will cause Flask to redirect to the canonical URL with
> the trailing slash.
>
> In the second case, however, the URL is defined without a trailing
> slash, rather like the pathname of a file on UNIX-like systems.
> Accessing the URL with a trailing slash will produce a 404 “Not Found”
> error.
>
> This behavior allows relative URLs to continue working even if the
> trailing slash is omitted, consistent with how Apache and other
> servers work. Also, the URLs will stay unique, which helps search
> engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

So just add `/users/` as well to the routing.