# Flask Blueprint Index URL keeps adding trailing slash

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

The blueprint is defined as

```
publicweb_bp = flask.Blueprint('publicweb', __name__, url_prefix='/<lang_code>/<country_code>/<market_code>')
```

I have an index route defined as

```
@publicweb_bp.route('/', strict_slashes = False)
def pp_index():
    return 'Hello'
```

and another route defined as

```
@publicweb_bp.route('/abc', strict_slashes = False)
def pp_index():
    return 'Abcdefg :P'
```

The problem is that when I access the url for e.g.

> http://localhost/en/us/m1

it always sends me to

> http://localhost/en/us/m1/

But if I access

> http://localhost/en/us/m1/abc

it keeps me on

> http://localhost/en/us/m1/abc

I have even tried playing with the strict_slashes option and turned it OFF , but has no effect.

It doesn't seem to work, even thought it works for all other URLs of the blueprint for e.g. '/abc'

Another thing I noticed was that if I don't use a blueprint and define a '/' route on the app itself with strict_slashes = False, it works as expected !

Comment: is abc path param?

Comment: The same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241050/trailing-slash-triggers-404-in-flask-path-rule). Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: actually you're telling the index route to match the `url_prefix` + `'/'`. Try to remove the slash and see if its working. Also try to make a request via curl, because, you know, browser has a cache.

Comment: Tried everything, doesn't seem to fix.

Comment: I have the same question, and think it's distinct from the thread linked by @DanilaGranchar. I think the difference between the url being a the index where the only content of the route itself is `/`, and a `abc` route which has other text to add or remove slashes from.  It seems like you should be able to ask the bp to apply the index slash non-strictly but didn't find a solve when looking.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```py
@publicweb_bp.route('', strict_slashes=False)
```

This works for me in Flask v1.1.1