# What difference between URL paths in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

What difference between URL paths:

```
@app.route('/projects')

@app.route('/projects/')
```

What does mean `slash` in the end of route path? In witch cases to use it?

If I understood correctly it is used for absolute and relative path to server files? Right?

Comment: See the *Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior* section in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rulesr)

Comment: I have seen this, but did not understand difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [trailing slash](https://www.thoughtco.com/urls-ending-with-slash-3466509).

#### For general `trailing slash`,

1. https://www.google.com/example/ -> It's a directory.

   - Firtst, Server checks if the directory exists.
   - Second, If it exists, server checks default file, such as `index.html`
2. https://www.google.com/example -> It's a file.

   - Firtst, Server checks if the file exists.
   - Second, if not, check the directory with that name.

Therefore, if you specify a trailing slash when requesting a directory resource, there is a small gain in page response speed because you can skip file checking.

#### In Flask

1. **`@app.route('/projects')`**

   - call to `/projects/`  -> return 404.
     (Werkzeug interprets as an explicit rule, so it's not match a trailing slash.)
   - call to `/projects`  -> return 200
2. **`@app.route('/projects/')`**

   - call to `/projects/`  -> return 200
   - call to `/projects`  -> return 302
     (Werkzeug will redirect if the url doesn't have it)

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241050/trailing-slash-triggers-404-in-flask-path-rule) will be helpful.