# Flask adds trailing slash to URL, no routes match

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

As per the title, Apache 2.4 seems to be appending '/' to the URL (according to `request.url`) and Flask's routes don't match with or without it.

**(relevant) File structure**

```
/var/www/wsgi
...
├── dizmo
│   └── __init__.py
├── foo.wsgi
├── hello1.wsgi
└── __pycache__
    └── adapter.cpython-35.pyc
```

**foo.wsgi**

```
import sys
import inspect
sys.path.append('/var/www/wsgi')
from dizmo import app as application
```

**dizmo/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import inspect
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
print( "app.config['SERVER_NAME']={}".format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']) )
print("{}:{} (outside)".format( inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename, inspect.currentframe().f_lineno ) )

@app.route('/foo')
@app.route('/foo/')
def tattletale():
    return 'I\'m foo'

@app.errorhandler(404)
def err_handler_404(error):
    return '{}: no route'.format(request.url), 404
```

**mysite.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    <Directory /var/www/wsgi>
        Require all granted
        DirectorySlash Off
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess CDRDB processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/python-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup CDRDB
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIScriptAlias /foo /var/www/wsgi/foo.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias /hello1 /var/www/wsgi/hello1.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

When it runs:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9000/foo
http://127.0.0.1:9000/foo/: no route
```

Notice the trailing slash in `request.url`.

I went through two dozen posts here and on Reddit regarding routes before I added the 404 handler, and now I'm at the end of my wits/rope. There's no 'foo' directory so `DirectorySlash` shouldn't even matter.

**Edit**: `strict_slashes=False` doesn't seem to change anything, as well as using a single decorator, `/foo` or `/foo/`.

**Edit 2**: Apparently, Apache or mod_wsgi plays tricks with the path, and `/foo/foo` somehow works. The Flask standalone server works as expected:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9000/foo/foo  # Apache
I'm foo. route=http://127.0.0.1:9000/foo/foo

curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo      # flask run
I'm foo. route=http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo
```

--

```
>>> flask.__version__
'0.12.2'
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
```

Comment: try adding `strict_slashes=False` to your route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trailing slash triggers 404 in Flask path rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241050/trailing-slash-triggers-404-in-flask-path-rule)

Comment: @noslenkwah, I already tried that with no luck - no idea why.

Comment: @sytech, I already went through that post

Comment: Have you tried `/foo/foo` ? It looks like your WSGI script alias is set to `/foo` -- If that doesn't work try running your app without Apache/WSGI and see if it works as expected

Comment: @sytech: getting a lot closer - the standalone Flask server accepts`http:..:5000/foo` and Apache works with `http:..:9000/foo/foo`, even with strict_slashes=True. Why, though? I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WSGIScriptAlias is misconfigured. Your app is being served by Apache relative to `/foo`

To get the behavior you want, the alias should be for the root directory, I.E. `/` instead of `/foo`

Comment: `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/...` works. Thanks a lot! To make it coexist with other script aliases, (eg `/hello` in my Apache .conf) I'm keeping the alias and decorating with `route('/')`, `route('/tweedledee')`, `route('/tweedledum')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one decorator between

```
@app.route('/foo')
@app.route('/foo/')
```

The second decorator causes also the redirect with final slash.

Comment: It fails with both decorators or either.

Comment: Having solved the issue (see sytech's answer), I tried adding a junk decorator before and after the useful one. Both work. Thanks for prompting me to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not need to specify the slash in the second decorator the flask is automatically redirect to that controller associated with your url

I also suggest you to remove the second decorator...