# Flask: The content of CSS disappear in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, routes

On my flask app, I have a route like following:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:articleId>')
def edit(articleId):
    article = Article.query.filter_by(id=articleId).first()
    return render_template('edit.html', article = article)
```

And in a template html file:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('edit', articleId=article.id) }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
```

**Question-1**:

When the `article.id == 1`, `url_for()` build a url `/edit/1` for me, and my browser (Chrome) would always add a trailing slash (`/edit/1/`) for me automatically. That lead to a "Page not found" issue. But when the `article.id >= 2`, it work well, chrome doesn't add a trailing slash anymore. I don't know why?

**Question-2**:

Encountering the Q1 above, I modify the route as following:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:articleId>')
@app.route('/edit/<int:articleId>/')
def edit(articleId):
    article = Article.query.filter_by(id=articleId).first()
    return render_template('edit.html', article = article)
```

Then another weird thing happen! When I access url `/edit/1` or `/edit/2` or `edit/<any valid integer>`, the content of CSS file are blank. I can see CSS files with Chrome `Developer Tool`, but the content of them is totally blank. Is it something trigger Chrome to block the CSS file?

Thanks for guiding!

Comment: The question-1 maybe duplicate with [Why is Google Chrome appending a forward slash to my flask url when there is none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013906/why-is-google-chrome-appending-a-forward-slash-to-my-flask-url-when-there-is-non)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365390/trailing-slash-in-flask-route for an answer on trailing slashes in Flask. The CSS issue is probably not related to the path, unless you are using relative paths for them, in which case you should check what is desired.