# Flask - Getting 404 on some routes inconsistently

Tags: python, flask, quart

The problem is simple

```
#This works
@app.route("/projects")
def user_home():
    return 'projects'

#This works
@app.route("/projects/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_project():
    return 'new project'

#This works
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>")
async def project_detail(project_id):
    return 'project detail'

#This works
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>/tasks")
def user_tasks(project_id):
    return 'project tasks'

#This gives a 404
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>/tasks/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_task(project_id):
    return 'new project task'

#This works
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>/tasks/<task_id>")
async def task_detail(project_id, task_id):
    return 'task detail'
```

The last route is giving me a 404 even though it follows the same logic as the ones above.

What is happening here?

If I could design my routes better I'm open to suggestions, It's a simple master/detail/CRUD app

(Tagging Quart as I'm actuallt using Quart but for now I'm assuming it doesn't matter since it has the same api as flask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm **not getting any error** with **your** code, kindly recheck. But maybe you could try

```
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>/tasks/new_task/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_task(project_id):
    return 'new project task'
```

Comment: Sorry, the error was based on another route I forgot to add, edited now

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241050/trailing-slash-triggers-404-in-flask-path-rule), the key problem is the interpretation with the lack of the forward slash by `Werkzeug`, which in return gives a 404 error.

> > Your /users route is missing a trailing slash, which Werkzeug interprets as an explicit rule to not match a trailing slash. Either add the trailing slash, and Werkzeug will redirect if the url doesn't have it, or set strict_slashes=False on the route and Werkzeug will match the rule with or without the slash

According to the [docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/routing/#rule-format):

> URL rules that end with a slash are branch URLs, others are leaves. If you have strict_slashes enabled (which is the default), all branch URLs that are visited without a trailing slash will trigger a redirect to the same URL with that slash appended.

So for your case, you can try:

```py
@app.route("/projects/<project_id>/tasks/new", methods=["GET", "POST"], strict_slashes=False)
def create_task(project_id):
    return 'new project task'
```

Comment: But the browser isn't trying to access it with a trailing slash, url_for correctly builds `.../tasks/new` . Adding strict_slashes didn't work.

Comment: Could there be an issue with having both `/projects/<project_id>/tasks` and `/projects/<project_id>/tasks/new` that the routes are confusing one for the other? If you try to add the forward slashes to both routes, would that work?

Comment: @Mojimi, the build _seems_ correct, but it is treating `../tasks/new` from the perspective of the `.../tasks/<task_id>` route, treating `new` as an _id_, because of the lack of the forward slash. Thing is, the route without the slash works because it is a different route. I highly recommend adding the  forward slash to `...tasks/new/` so it becomes a new route (branch) and not an element of another route.