# String to pandas Dataframe based on columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, flask

I am sending an ajax GET request to a flask server (`http://localhost:5000/req/?q=139,2,10,60,5,1462,7,5,6,9,17,78`) in order to retrieve some values and assign them to a Dataframe. Doing it manually, it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[139,2,10,60,5,1462,7,5,6,9,17,78]],columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12'])
```

but i need the numbers to come from **request.args** via ajax and then be based in the Dataframe as an array.

```
@app.route('/req/', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    args = dict(request.args.to_dict())
    t = request.args["q"]
    return getResults(t), 200
```

And the getResults() would be something like:

```
def getResults(name):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[name]], columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12'])
    """"
```

but of course this doesn't work. Gives an error: ValueError: 12 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

How can i do this ? I've tried splitting the string, try to convert to an array..nothing worked.

Comment: Why `args = dict(request.args.to_dict())` ? request.args is already a nice dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The args is resolved as a string, so after `t = request.args["q"]`, `t` is `"139,2,10,60,5,1462,7,5,6,9,17,78"`, you need a list of int

```
@app.route('/req') # GET only is default method
def foo():
    t = request.args["q"]
    t = [int(val) for val in t.split(",")]
    return getResults(t) # 200 is the default status code
```

And

```
def getResults(name):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[name], # no extra []
```

---

Also prefer `/req` (that allows both with and without trailing slash) rather than `/req/` that accept only one , [refer to this for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241050/trailing-slash-triggers-404-in-flask-path-rule#answers)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @azro, just a small fix, it is: int(val) for val  (not van), and for anyone else, in the function it should be: pd.DataFrame(data=[name].....   ps: i will accept it in 4 min :) Thanks again!